# Asynchronous block in a loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, asynchronous, cllocation

How can I manage calling an asynchronous block in a loop?

My code to be called n-times:

```
- (void) convertToCountries:(NSString*)time longitude:(NSString*)lon latitude:(NSString*)lat {


CLLocation *myLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[lat doubleValue] longitude:[lon doubleValue]];


[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:myLocation
               completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                   NSLog(@"reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler: Completion Handler called!");

                   if (error){
                       NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                       return;
                   }

                   if(placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
                   {
                       //do something
                       CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                       NSString *addressTxt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %@,%@ %@", [topResult country],
                                               [topResult subThoroughfare],[topResult thoroughfare],
                                               [topResult locality], [topResult administrativeArea]];
                       NSLog(@"%@",addressTxt);

                       NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                       [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

                       //Optionally for time zone converstions
                       [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"..."]];


                       [DataOperations saveRecord:[topResult country] time:time];

                   }
               }];

}
```

I need to collect output data from these calls.

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: which problem are you having?

Comment: Since it is asynchronous call, it does not wait until the results are processed and then continue. The loop is done with just first parameters.

Comment: and what would you do instead? sequencing the calls (e.g., wait for one to complete, and use it results)?

Comment: I am asking for the best approach regarding this situation. I have n records with latitude and longitude and those params are needed to be called with this function to get results for each record. I have done it recursively, but I do not like the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your object a property, `BOOL dunloadin`.

Then, in the completion block, set `self.dunloadin` to `YES`.

Finally, your loop should look something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    self.dunloadin = NO;
    [self convertToCountries:…];

    while (!self.dunloadin)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }
}
```

However, you might want to consider designing your app differently so that kludges like this aren't required.